# Migrating Active Model Serializer from 0.8 to 0.10 rc2

Tags: active-model-serializers

We've got an API built with Grape and Active Model Serializers 0.8. Now we would like to use all the caching goodness from 0.10, so a migration to the new backwards-incompatible version is in progress.

There are currently two issues right now:

1. It doesn't seem possible to redefine the root key with `self.root=` inside serializers. E.g. we've got `SimpleUserSerializer` and we want the root key to `user` instead of `simple_user`. A solution is to specify the root when rendering the serializer, but then we need to make the change in many places. Is there a way to redefine the root key for this serializers regardless of where/how it's rendered?
2. `embed :ids, include: true` option is not supported and should probably be implemented through an adapter. Are there any plans on releasing or maintaining 0.8-compatible adapter for legacy projects?

Any guidance about the migration would be helpful as I couldn't find any official documentation.

Answer (score 2):

The first issue can be resolved by defining class method `root_name` which returns the root key. This can be seen in [fixtures in AMS tests](https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/e1c25e86e35b810a7fbe11ba322da8a7a430e106/test/fixtures/poro.rb#L109).

Still working on the second issue.

Answer (score -1):

the official guide can be helpful:
https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers/blob/0-10-stable/docs/howto/upgrade_from_0_8_to_0_10.md

If it does not help, try this:

```
In the previous version, we would specify the root as follows:

class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  self.root = "application_user"
end
or:

class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  root "application_user"
end
They both stopped working after the upgrade and we had to change it to:

class UserSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  type "application_user"
end
```

And this:

```
Root key not included in JSON
To fix that we had to configure json as the adapter (the new library default is attributes).

ActiveModelSerializers.config.adapter = :json
```

The full upgrade guide here:
http://engineering.liefery.com/2017/11/07/upgrading-active-model-serializers-from-0-8-to-0-10.html